# Qpython3 and androidhelper, droid.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems

Tags: qpython

I am trying to figure out androidhelper, which I find very useful to work with python 3 and Android.  I am trying to return a selection from a list using dialogSetChoiceItems.  I have it set up, and I have tried various ways of going about it.  I will get something returned, but it is the length of the list.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks,

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3 
#qpy:console
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()

def test_alert_dialog_with_single_choice_list(Title, ListOfStuff):

  droid.dialogCreateAlert(Title)
  droid.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(ListOfStuff)

  droid.dialogSetPositiveButtonText('Select')
  droid.dialogShow()
  response = droid.dialogGetSelectedItems().result
  return response





if __name__ == '__main__':

    Listy = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    YTitle = 'Title of The Thing'

    FReturn = test_alert_dialog_with_single_choice_list(YTitle, Listy)

    print(FReturn)
```

Comment: `droid.dialogGetSelectedItems().result` should return a list of selected items' indexes, documentation [here](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/UiFacade.html#dialogGetSelectedItems). What did you get? the length of the list?

Comment: I get the default selected item of [0].  If I change droid.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(ListOfStuff, selected=None)  If I change droid.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(ListOfStuff, selected=3), it returns 3.  If I remove .result from response = droid.dialogGetSelectedItems(), I get the following:  Result(id=5, result=[0], error=None).   I can't get any return from the list.  I have tried having the list in the function without passing it through a variable, nothing works.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the problem is. Are you expecting `droid.dialogGetSelectedItems().result` to return the "selected items" in your list? No, it doesn't. It returns "seleted items' indexes" as a list. For example, if you give it items["a","b","c","d"], it'll return [0] if you selected "a", [1] if "b", [2] if "c"... Is this the problem? Maybe I'll write an example code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example makes a dialog with "xyz" buttons and "abcde" items, then `print(pressed_button, selected_items_indexes)`, and `makeToast` your pressed button and selected items. Try it! It worked fine on my phone, tell me if it doesn't on your phone.

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:console
import androidhelper
droid=androidhelper.Android()
def mydialog(title,buttons=["OK"],items=[],multi=False):
    title = str(title)
    droid.dialogCreateAlert(title)
    if len(items) > 0:
        if multi:
            droid.dialogSetMultiChoiceItems(items)
        else:
            droid.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(items)
    if len(buttons) >= 1:
        droid.dialogSetPositiveButtonText(buttons[0])
    if len(buttons) >= 2:
        droid.dialogSetNeutralButtonText(buttons[1])
    if len(buttons) >= 3:
        droid.dialogSetNegativeButtonText(buttons[2])
    droid.dialogShow()
    res0 = droid.dialogGetResponse().result
    res = droid.dialogGetSelectedItems().result
    if "which" in res0.keys():
        res0={"positive":0,"neutral":1,"negative":2}[res0["which"]]
    else:
        res0=-1
    return res0,res
items = [i for i in "abcde"]
btns = [i for i in "xyz"]
pressed_button, selected_items_indexes = mydialog("Dialog test!", btns, items, True)
print(pressed_button, selected_items_indexes)
if pressed_button == -1:
    droid.makeToast("You didn't press any buttons!")
else:
    droid.makeToast("You pressed %s!"%("xyz"[pressed_button]))
if selected_items_indexes == []:
    droid.makeToast("You selected nothing!")
else:
    selected_abc = "".join(["abcde"[i] for i in selected_items_indexes])
    droid.makeToast("You selected %s!"%selected_abc)
```